# Bash script evaluates differently via term and MacOS launchd

Tags: bash, macos, launchd

I have a very simple bash script that curls a URL, counts a substring in the response, and runs some code if it finds the string.

Originally, I wrote it like this:

```
RESP=$(curl -s 'https://theurl.com' | grep -ic substring)

if [ $RESP > 0 ];
  do something
else
  do something else
fi
```

This worked great from my terminal prompt.

When I set it up to run in launchd as a local user launch agent, the if statement never evaluated to true.

Things I tried during debugging:

1. Ensuring both were using /bin/bash (they were) and running as me.
2. Sending the variable to stdout to confirm.
3. Running them without the curl, just grepping a local file.

Eventually, I was able to get it to work by changing the if to:

```
if [ $RESP -ge 1 ]
```

That works in both places, but I can't figure out why the exact same script in the exact same interpreter would evaluate differently in both places.

Any ideas?

Comment: After `[ $RESP > 0 ];` you are missing a `then`. However, without the `then` I'd expect the script to always fail. Did you just miss it in your question?

Comment: Does the script begin with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: With `sh` or `bash` `[ $RESP > 0 ]` creates a file named `0`.

Comment: General rule in bash comparisons inside `[` or `[[`: use the "lettery" comparison `-gt` for numbers, and the "numbery" comparison `>` for strings, the opposite of what you'd think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `>` doesn't do what you think it does. The command

```
[ $RESP > 0 ]
```

is treated by the shell as a funny way of writing

```
[ $RESP ] > 0
```

That is, it runs the command `[` (yes, that's an actual command, essentially equivalent to `test`) with the expansion of `$RESP` and "`]`" as arguments. The fact that `> 0` is in the middle of the arguments to `[` doesn't matter; you can put a redirection operator anywhere in the command ... argument(s) sequence, and it does the same thing.

Net result: `[` checks to see if `$RESP` expands to a non-blank string (succeeding if it does), and sends its (empty) output to a file named "0".

At least, that's what it does normally. I suspect when you run it as launch agent, it's getting an error creating the "0" file, so it fails. And since it fails, and it's the condition of an `if` statement, the `else` clause runs.

To use `>` or `<` in a `[ ]` test expression, you need to quote or escape it, like `[ "$RESP" ">" 0 ]` or `[ "$RESP" \> 0 ]`. Also, `>` is the wrong test operator anyway; if you're comparing integers, use `-gt` instead. In a `[ ]` test expression, `>` denotes sorting order comparsion (so `[ 9 ">" 10 ]` is true, because "9" sorts after "1").

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it had something to do with the evaluation syntax but I could not figure out why worked in my own shell. This explains it. If launchd would have thrown an error I would have zeroed in on it quickly. Thanks for the bash lesson!

Comment: @MichaelM Unfortunately, launchd jobs run without any connection to the user interface, so they don't have a good way to report errors. For debugging, you can direct standard & error output to files by adding the `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys to the .plist. But note that you need to send them somewhere the job has permissions to write to.

Answer (score 2):

This seems very strange, but as Cyrus pointed out in the comments, the command `[ $RESP > 0 ]` creates a file named `0`. If you run the script from launchd the creation of such a file probably fails because the working directory is different from when you run the script in your terminal. Because the file could not be created, the `if ...` check fails and the `else` branch is entered.

Now, why on earth does this create a file. `bash -c 'help test'` (`[` is a synonym for `test`) clearly states

> STRING1 > STRING2
> True if STRING1 sorts after STRING2 lexicographically.

However, before `test`/`[` sees the `>` bash processes it and interprets it as a redirection. The following three commands are actually equivalent:

```
echo string > file
echo > file string 
> file echo string
```

Therefore, you do the test `[ $RESP ]` and redirect the (empty) output to the file `0`.

To use the `>` from `test` you have to quote it, like so: `[ $RESP ">" 0 ]`. However, as you already noticed, you wanted to use `-gt` instead.

**Note:** To check if any matches were found you could switch to `grep -q` instead:

```
if curl -s 'https://theurl.com' | grep -iq substring; then
  # do something
else
  # do something else
fi
```